# Set width text to a value that changes over time in a NumberAnimation

Tags: qt, qml

```
Rectangle {
    id: rect3
    width: 50
    height: 50
    x: 75
    y: 330
    color: "#FF4C3B"
    Text {
        id: text3
        x: 8
        y: 0
        width: 50
        height: 50
        color: "#FFFFFF"
        font.family: "Ubuntu"
        text: "►"
        font.pixelSize: 40
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true
            onEntered: {
                animation5.start()
                text3.text= "abcdefghijklmno"
                text3.width=animation5.width
            }
            onExited: {
                animation6.start()
                text3.text="►"
                text3.width=animation6.width
            }
            NumberAnimation {
                id: animation5
                target: rect3
                property: "width"
                to: 350;
                duration: 1000
            }
            NumberAnimation {
                id: animation6
                target: rect3
                property: "width"
                to: 50;
                duration: 1000
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can I set the width of the text to be bound to the width that gets increased/decreased in the NumberAnimations? I want the text to scale in size at once with the rectangle. I thought that `text3.width=animation5.width` in the `onEntered` function and `text3.width=animation6.width` in the `onExited` function would do it but it didn't really seem like? Any ideas?

EDIT: I've also tried creating another NumberAction for the width of the text but it still doesn't work

Comment: Assuming I've got your point there, it is an error to assign directly a value to the width (imperative code vs. binding). Also some aspect should be handled differently. What about [this approach](http://pastebin.com/raw/QSnZbV0m)? It seems to work as expected. Please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the response but meanwhile I've solved the issue. What I actually had to do is to just increase text3.x's value for which I've added another NumberAnimation. What I've wanted the program to do is to just move the text, kind of like a slide-in if you think about it. Since I'm pretty new to qt/qml I really didn't know what i had to actually do about this, but I've figured it out in the end. Really appreciate the help though!

Comment: Ok, good. Please insert your answer and accept it. That said, be sure to read [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-propertybinding.html) to avoid error while using bindings. That's one of the trickest aspect, at least while you are a rookie. Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Rectangle {
id: rect3
width: 50
height: 50
x: 75
y: 330
color: "#FF4C3B"
Text {
    id: text3
    x: 8
    y: 0
    width: 50
    height: 50
    color: "#FFFFFF"
    font.family: "Ubuntu"
    text: "►"
    font.pixelSize: 40
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
        onEntered: {
            animation5.start()
            text3.text= "abcdefghijklmno"
            textanim5.start()
        }
        onExited: {
            animation6.start()
            text3.text="►"
            textanim6.start()
        }
        NumberAnimation {
            id: animation5
            target: rect3
            property: "width"
            to: root.width-150;
            duration: (10*(root.width-150))/3.5
        }
        NumberAnimation {
            id: animation6
            target: rect3
            property: "width"
            to: 50;
            duration: (10*(root.width-150))/3.5
        }
        NumberAnimation {
            id: textanim5
            target: text3
            property: "x"
            to: root.width-200
            duration: (10*(root.width-150))/3.5
        }
        NumberAnimation {
            id: textanim6
            target: text3
            property: "x"
            to: 8
            duration: (10*(root.width-150))/3.5
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If the target of animation is Rectangle:

```
Rectangle {
    ...
    Text {
        ...
        width: parent.width
}
```

Comment: still doesn't work. the width of the text just remains a constant value